# Managing multiple terraform statefiles with gitlab

Tags: gitlab, terraform

Just as an example, my git repository would look like so:

```
└── git_repo_example
    ├── modules
    │   ├── module_1
    │   │   ├── main.tf
    │   │   └── var.tf
    │   └── module_2
    │       ├── main.tf
    │       └── var.tf
    └── projects
        ├── project_1
        │   ├── main.tf
        │   ├── terraform.tfstate
        │   └── vars.tf
        └── project_2
            ├── main.tf
            ├── terraform.tfstate
            └── vars.tf

7 directories, 10 files
```

My team wants to make our terraform state files gitlab-managed, so that the statefiles would be locked in case multiple people want to run or modify a single project at the same time.

All of the examples I can find for managing terraform via gitlab only seem to assume 1 tfstate file and project, but my repository has multiple. Breaking this up into multiple repositories would be difficult to manage since they all reference the same modules, and it seems that placing everything into one folder is against terraform best-practices.

How would one best go about managing one repository with multiple terraform projects / statefiles via gitlab?

Comment: "statefiles would be locked..." - Git's purpose is just the opposite: to allow distributed and concurrent work on code *without* locking (unless you're plugging in something like [Git-LFS](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/file_lock.html#exclusive-file-locks)?)

Comment: You're better off properly versioning/distributing the module than trying to put everything in one project just so you can use the module in the same repo.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar-ish directory structure that works well with GitLab managed state per project directory.

I'd recommend replacing local TF development with GitLab CI/CD pipelines, using the provided GitLab container image as it supports the GitLab backend by default.

I use environments (representing each project directory) to mange the pipeline (CI/CD variables are managed by environment). The TF statefile is named according to the `TF_ADDRESS` variable:

```yaml
image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/stable:latest

variables:
  TF_ROOT: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${ENVIRONMENT}
  TF_ADDRESS: ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/${ENVIRONMENT}
```

Here a build job is defined to create the TF plan and run only when the `development` directory is modified and merged to the default branch. An identical job for the `production` directory is also defined. Each environment references a unique TF state file managed by GitLab:

```yaml
.plan:
  stage: build
  environment: 
    name: $ENVIRONMENT
  script:
    - gitlab-terraform plan
    - gitlab-terraform plan-json
  cache:
    policy: pull # don't update the cache
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/plan.cache
    reports:
      terraform: ${TF_ROOT}/plan.json

Development Build Terraform Plan:
  extends: .plan
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT: development
  rules:
     - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
       changes:
        - "*"
        - "development/**/*"

Production Build Terraform Plan:
  extends: .plan
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT: production
  rules:
     - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
       changes:
        - "*"
        - "production/**/*"
```

Comment: Under "rules.changes" you have two patterns listed, one being just an asterisk. Why do you have that? Wouldn't you want just changes under the directory for the environment? Wouldn't the single asterisk catch *all* changes, and therefore make "changes:" redundant? I don't understand what you're doing there.

Comment: Bad copy and paste on my part, the standalone wildcard negates the subdirectory listed below it. I assembled the comment from existing yaml that I didn't want to include directly to protect confidential information.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same kind of terraform scripts repository, with a "run" script at the top, which will do, for each application, a

```
cd modules/modulesx
terraform init -backend-config=backend.tf -reconfigure
```

With backend.tf (here for Azure):

```
container-name = "tfbackend"
key = "aStorageAccount/aFileShare/path/to/modulex.tfstate"
resource_group_name = "xxx"
```

That does create a `modules/modulex/.terraform/terraform.tfstate`

However, this file is local and not versioned nor "locked".